# How to make DOMDocument write standalone=yes in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm using PHP5 to create XML files. I have code like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
...
$xml_content = $doc->saveXML();
```

The problem is that created XML code starts with a root node like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
```

I guess I need to call some function on $doc, but I can't figure out which one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to set

```
$doc->xmlStandalone = true;
```

It's not a function of the class, it's a property so it's a little harder to find in the docs.  You can read about it [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).